# Difference in implementation of classes and objects in java and C++

Tags: java, c++, oop

I wrote the following code in java :

```
class node{
  int key;
  node left ,right;
  public node(int item ){
  key = item;
  left = right = NULL;
 }
```

it works fine in java but when i try to implement the same thing in c++ , it shows an error saying,"error: field 'left' has incomplete type 'node'".
Can anyone explain how is this happening ? and what can i do to remove this error? i want to know how these two languages are implementing this.

Comment: In C++, you must use pointer to achieve the same thing as the `node left, right;` you have in Java. E.g. `node * left, right;`. Btw, you should name your class `Node` and not `node`.

Comment: @DatNguyen That declaration only declares `left` as a pointer. And the upper/lower case of the first character in the class name is up to personal preference or company style guides.

Comment: C++ is not Java.  Please don't use Java as a model in writing C++ code.

Answer (score 6):

In Java, when you declare a variable of some object type, you really only declare it as a *reference* to the object. In C++ an object declared as

```
node left;
```

says that `left` is an actual *instance* of the `node` class. And to be able to define an instance the full definition of the class is needed.

Inside a class, when declaring member variables and functions, the class isn't actually fully defined yet, it doesn't happen until the closing `}`.

To declare a variable to be a reference you need to use the `&` character, like

```
node& left;
```

Or use pointers, as in

```
node* left;
```

Pointers are the most common when one needs to link to objects, because the semantics for references are such that once initialized a reference can not be changed to reference another object.

All of this, and much more, should be [in any good beginners C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), which I recommend you find and read one.